# Problema con generar un cargo con Stripe con mxn mayor a $10

Tags: php, laravel, stripe

El problema que tengo es que al momento de generar el cargo en stripe este debe ser mayor a $10 acuerdo a la documentación ([doc](https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#zero-decimal)), sin embargo, al momento de generar al cargo me sale el error de que debe ser mayor a $10 mxn, el cual cumple pero hasta no ser mayor o igual a 1000 es como no tengo problemas, me ayudarían demasiado.

```
        return $stripe->charges->create(
        [
            'amount' =>    100,
            'currency' => 'mxn',
            'source' => $tokToken,
            'customer' => $idCus,
            'description' => $desc
        ]
    );
```

Comment: El problema es que estás malinterpretando la documentación. La moneda MXN no está listada como *zero-decimal*, por lo tanto debes convertir `$10 MXN` a su equivalente en céntimos: `amount: 1000` (hay mil céntimos en 10 unidades). Tu estás pasando 100 como valor, lo cual equivale sólo a `$1 MXN`. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es que estás malinterpretando la documentación. La moneda `MXN` no está listada como `zero-decimal`, por lo tanto debes convertir $100 MXN a su equivalente en céntimos.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es sencilla, según la [documentación](https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#zero-decimal), los montos de las monedas que no se encuentran en la lista de `zero-decimal` deben ser convertidos a su equivalente en céntimos. El monto mínimo para la moneda `MXN` es de `$10` , que al convertirlo a céntimos resulta en: `1000` (hay mil céntimos en 10 unidades). Tu estás pasando 100 como valor, lo cual equivale sólo a $1 MXN.

Por lo tanto, lo correcto es:

```php
'amount' => 10000 // esto equivale a $100
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.